# Ruby exception: `incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii, protocol-buffers

**Important information is on the bottom line!**

Rails application encounters exception when serializing Protocol Buffers message:

> Exception(Encoding::CompatibilityError): incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8

```
==== Stack trace: ====
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/ruby-protocol-buffers-1.5.1/lib/protocol_buffers/runtime/encoder.rb:64:in `write'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/ruby-protocol-buffers-1.5.1/lib/protocol_buffers/runtime/encoder.rb:64:in `serialize_field_value'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/ruby-protocol-buffers-1.5.1/lib/protocol_buffers/runtime/encoder.rb:51:in `serialize_field'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/ruby-protocol-buffers-1.5.1/lib/protocol_buffers/runtime/encoder.rb:38:in `block in encode'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/ruby-protocol-buffers-1.5.1/lib/protocol_buffers/runtime/encoder.rb:15:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/ruby-protocol-buffers-1.5.1/lib/protocol_buffers/runtime/encoder.rb:15:in `encode'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/ruby-protocol-buffers-1.5.1/lib/protocol_buffers/runtime/message.rb:248:in `serialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/ruby-protocol-buffers-1.5.1/lib/protocol_buffers/runtime/message.rb:255:in `serialize_to_string'
/var/www/html/disp/lib/navs/navs.rb:955:in `compose_message'
```

The line 955 is:

```
[type].pack('N*') + msg.serialize_to_string
```

where `type` is integer and `msg` is an descendant of `ProtocolBuffers::Message`.

**Important information**

I encounter this exception only on one CentOS machine in any web server (Apache+Passenger, WEBrick, Puma). On Windows and other CentOS machine everything is fine. Code is the same, database is re-created and seeded every time before test.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by downgrading Ruby from 2.0.0-p576 to 2.0.0-p481

**Update**

p481 is no more available for download.